# Qual o antônimo de "Interseção" quando falo de Conjuntos (matemática)?

Tags: antónimos

Considerando um conceito básico de conjuntos:

Conjunto A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
Conjunto B = [ 3, 4, 5, 6 ]

A Interseção de A e B é = [ 3, 4 ]

"O oposto da interseção" é = [1, 2, 5, 6]

Qual palavra posso utilizar para "Oposto da Interseção" ?

---

Vou listar as opções que encontrar, e que "teoricamente" estão na direção certa:

1. Descruzar: https://www.dicio.com.br/descruzar/
2. Segregação: https://www.significados.com.br/segregacao/
3. Discrepância: https://www.dicio.com.br/discrepancia/

---

conceitos opostos à interseção:

1. Diferença Simétrica: [https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferença_simétrica](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferen%C3%A7a_sim%C3%A9trica)
2. Disjunção Exclusiva: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Porta_XOR

---

Lembrando que: a pergunta é se existe uma palavra antônima para Interseção ?

Answer (score 8):

Pode utilizar "diferença simétrica". A diferença simétrica de dois conjuntos A e B é o conjunto de elementos que estão em A ou em B, mas não na sua intersecção.

Para mais detalhes, ver [*Diferença Simétrica* na Wikipédia.](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diferen%C3%A7a_sim%C3%A9trica)

Comment: obrigado, o conceito oposto eu já conhecia, o que eu queria saber é se existe uma palavra oposta. Tipo: "desconjunção" (junção) ou "segregação" (integração)

Comment: João, acho que o link fica mais bonito assim como eu o deixei. Mas se não concordades, imagino que saibas fazer rollback...

Comment: Sim, Jacinto, fica. Obrigado! :)

Comment: É uma boa pergunta! Não sei a resposta, mas "disjunção" parece-me mais adequada do que "desconjunção".